# WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws, readystate

I am trying to get real time data from the Alpaca API. At first, I can connect to the API and it streams the data. But after some time it gets me an error.

Here is my code:

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const Alpaca = require('@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api');
const alpaca = new Alpaca({
  keyId: process.env.ALPACA_API_KEY_ID,
  secretKey: process.env.ALPACA_API_SECRET_KEY,
  paper: true, 
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`Client connected with ID: ${socket.id}`);
  let stream = null;

  socket.on('subscribe', (ticker) => {

    console.log(`Subscribing to data for ${ticker}`);

    const stream = alpaca.data_stream_v2;
    stream.onConnect(function () {
        console.log("Connected");
        stream.subscribeForQuotes([(ticker)]);
      });
  
      stream.onStockQuote((quote) => {
        console.log(quote);
        socket.emit('stockData', quote);
      });

      stream.connect();

  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Client disconnected with ID: ${socket.id}`);
    if (stream) {
      console.log(`Unsubscribing from data for ${stream.ticker}`);
      stream.disconnect();
    }
  });
});
```

and this is the error I get:

```html
/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:394
      throw new Error('WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)');
      ^

Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)
    at WebSocket.send (/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:394:13)
    at AlpacaStocksClient.authenticate (/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api/dist/resources/datav2/websocket.js:171:19)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/@alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api/dist/resources/datav2/websocket.js:108:43)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at WebSocket.setSocket (/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:225:10)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/vivien/Documents/tradingapp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:882:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:527:11)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Do you know why I get this error and what I can do to make it work?

Comment: If you log the reason, what does it say? `socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => { console.log(reason); });`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get real time data from the Alpaca API. At first, I **can connect to the API and it streams the data. But after some time it gets me an error**.

The most possible cause it's because your websocket got disconnected and trying reconnect while you are sending a message. The best you can do is research why it disconnects.